# Passing parameters to Lazy singleton GetInstance

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation

I am using the `.NET 4's Lazy<T> type` method to create a singleton instance. But I want to pass three file paths of configuration files to the property `Instance` that returns the singleton

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the singleton pattern is not well-suited for your use case. Perhaps you could try a factory pattern instead and let the factory provide you with a properly configured instance.

Answer (score 5):

Can you share with us the reason why your class needs to be a singleton? Perhaps you can use an IoC container, in such case you can ensure that there's just one instance of your class in IoC set-up.

If you really want to use a singleton, maybe think about adding some init/config method. Your singleton would have to be initialized before accessing the instance (throw an exception if it isn't). I don't like this solution, as users of the Singleton class need to know somehow about the init step.

Comment: Can IoC containers ensure that only once instance exists ? I am not familiar with the concept.

Comment: Yeah, IoC containers like StructureMap would allow you to specify that in the bootstrapping of the application http://structuremap.github.io/object-lifecycle/supported-lifecycles/

Comment: @liv2hak did you manage to use the code above or decided to use IOC?

Comment: @jedgard It seems that [structuremap has been sunsetted](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/README.markdown), for IoC implementation here there is a post with a list of [active .NET dependency injection frameworks](https://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2019/01/24/the-ultimate-list-of-net-dependency-injection-frameworks/)

Comment: @MichałŻołnieruk This code does not compile. `Init` is treated as static ctor. In must return either with `void` or with a `Singleton`.  `lazy` private member can't be `readonly` because it is initialized in a static method.

Answer (score -1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Singleton class
/// </summary>
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Lazy<Singleton> lazy = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// You can use this param to pass to your base class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    private Singleton(int parameter)
    {

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creating single object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Singleton CreateSingletonObj(int parameter)
    {
        if (lazy == null)
        {
            lazy = new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton(parameter));
        }
        return lazy.Value;
    }
}
```